# Mid 90s fantasy novel. Main character is similar to a brownie, has a skeleton companion

Tags: story-identification, demons

I'm looking for a book where the main character is a little person.  Maybe 2- 3 inches tall.  Part of a Brownie race, but I don't think they were brownies.

One of the characters was an animate skeleton (this is not Marrow from Xanth).

Another is a succubus or demon woman who I think starts out as the bad guy's minion and turns good.

There's a part near the end where one of them shares bone marrow to help heal another and one of them shares half their soul.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say the animated skeleton is not Marrow from the Piers Anthony Xanth books, but this sounds awfully like *Harpy Thyme*. The main character is Gloha who is half harpy and half goblin. The demoness is Metria.

The sharing of bone marrow is when Marrow donates some of his bone marrow to Graeboe the giant.

The sharing of souls is when Graboe donates half his soul to Marrow in return.

Comment: Might be.  I'm picking up a copy to confirm.  I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, it's Harpy Thyme.  Thanks, John.  Been so long since I read the book I had to pore over the last couple pages a few times before everything lined up with my memories.  It wasn't until Gloha was wiping Graboe's wounds with the healing elixir that it finally all clicked.